# Arrow law: first depends only on the first component of the pair. Why do we need this one?

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows, combinators, kleisli

John Hughes in his "Generalising Monads to Arrows" writes (chapter 8):

> We formalise the property that `first f` depends only on first components of pairs as follows:
> `first f >>> arr fst = arr fst >>> f`

I understand that the law filters out implementations of such sort:

```
newtype KleisliMaybe a b = KMb { runKMb :: a -> Maybe b }

instance Category KleisliMaybe where 
 ...

instance Arrow KleisliMaybe where
 first f = KMb $ const Nothing
 ...
```

But the wording seems a bit odd for this case (I would have chosen "`first` has no side-effects" or something like that for such an instance).

So, what are other reasons to keep it around?

Moreover, there is another law: `first f >>> second (arr g) = second (arr g) >>> first f`. I did not find any implementations it filters out *(I did - see the edit)*. How does this law help us?

---

**Edit: more thoughts on the latter law.**

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
newtype KleisliWriter = KW { runKW :: a -> (String, b) }

instance Category KleisliWriter where
 ...

instance Arrow KleisliWriter where
 arr f = KW $ \ x -> ("", f x)
 first  (KW f) = KW $ \ ~(a, d) -> f a >>= (\ x -> ("A", (x, d)))
 second (KW f) = KW $ \ ~(d, b) -> f b >>= (\ x -> ("B", (d, x)))
```

Such an instance behaves this way:

```
GHCi> c = KW $ \ x -> ("C", x)
GHCi> fst . runKW (first c >>> second (arr id)) $ (1, 2)
"CAB"
GHCi> fst . runKW (second (arr id) >>> first c) $ (1, 2)
"BCA"
```

As far as I get it, we have got no law for `second f = swap >>> first f >>> swap`. Therefore, we can forbid both `second` and `first` to have any side-effects with this law. Yet, the original wording still does not seem to hint at that again:

> ...we formalise the intuition that the second component of the pair is unaffected by `first f` as a law...

Are those laws just pure formalisations for solid proofs?

Comment: In `Kleisli IO`, would you say that `first (K (\a -> print 4 >> pure (a+1)))` has no side effects?

Comment: @chi I probably would say that about `first` for `Kleisli`, not the entire expression. If we call the `first`'s argument `f`, `arr fst >>> f` would not lack the side-effects of `first f >>> arr fst`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I believe all this law is really saying is that `arr fst :: a (x, v) x` is a natural transformation from the functor `first :: a x y -> a (x, v) (y, v)` to the functor `id :: a x y -> a x y`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Unfortunately, I am not sure I know what "natural transformation" is. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Sure. Are you familiar with the basic idea of categories and functors? If not, an article on this topic might provide a much better explanation than I could fit into a comment.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin if you mean the formal understanding (or any that goes beyond the Haskell class types), I am probably not. What article could you recommend?

Comment: If you're familiar with the `Category` class from Haskell (which is a superclass of `Arrow`), I think you already have a good understanding of categories. [Functors](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/20/functors/) and [natural transformations](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations/) in their more general form are well explained well on Bartosz Milewski's blog IMO.

Comment: What I'm saying above is that there are a couple of endofunctors on every arrow category: `(, v)` and the identity functor. The stated law takes the form of a "naturality square" `map1 f . n = n . map2 f`: it simply demands that `arr fst` is a natural transformation between these two functors.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin [Related to your explanation in terms of **natural transformations**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639328/how-arr-fst-is-a-natural-transformation).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**  There's a different pair of laws that cover "`first` and `second` have no side-effects":

```
first (arr f) = arr (first f)
second (arr f) = arr (second f)
```

After thinking about it, I **THINK** that both laws you've identified:

```
first f >>> arr fst          =   arr fst >>> f                -- LAW-A
first f >>> second (arr g)   =   second (arr g) >>> first f   -- LAW-B
```

are, in fact, redundant because they follow from those no-side-effects laws, the other laws, and a couple of "free theorems".

Your counterexamples violate the no-side-effects laws, so that's why they also violate LAW-A and/or LAW-B.  If someone has a true counterexample that obeys the no-side-effects laws but violates LAW-A or LAW-B, I'd be very interested in seeing it.

**Long answer:**

The property "`first` has no side effects (of its own, at least)" is better formalized by the law stated earlier in Section 8 of that article:

```
first (arr f) = arr (first f)
```

Recall that Hughes says an arrow is "pure" (equivalently, "has no side-effects") if it can be written `arr expr`.  So, this law states that, given any computation that is already pure and so can be written `arr f`, applying `first` to that computation also results in a pure computation (because it is of the form `arr expr` with `expr = first f`).  Therefore, `first` introduces no impurities / no effects of its own.

The other two laws:

```
first f >>> arr fst          =   arr fst >>> f                -- LAW-A
first f >>> second (arr g)   =   second (arr g) >>> first f   -- LAW-B
```

are intended to capture the idea that for a particular `instance Arrow Foo` and a particular arrow action `f :: Foo B C`, the action:

```
first f :: forall d. Foo (B,d) (C,d)
```

acts on the first components of its input/output pairs as if the second components weren't there.  The laws correspond to the properties:

1. LAW-A: the output component `C` and any side effects depend only on input `B`, not input `d` (i.e., no dependence on `d`)
2. LAW-B: the component `d` passes through unchanged, unaffected by the input `B` or any side effects (i.e., no effect on `d`)

With respect to LAW-A, if we consider the action `first f :: Foo (B,d) (C,d)` and focus on the `C` component of its output using a pure function to extract it:

```
first f >>> arr fst :: Foo (B,d) C
```

then the result is the same as if we first forcibly remove the second component using a pure action:

```
arr fst :: Foo (B,d) B
```

and allow the original action `f` to act only on `B`:

```
arr fst >>> f :: Foo (B,d) C
```

Here, the structure of the `first f >>> arr fst` action leaves open the possibility that `first f` can depend on the `d` component of the input in formulating its side effects and constructing the `C` component of its output; but, the structure of the `arr fst >>> f` action eliminates this possibility by removing the `d` component via a pure action before allowing any non-trivial computation by `f`.  The fact that these two actions are equal (the law) makes it clear that `first f` produces a `C` output (and side effects, through `f`, since `first` has no additional effects of its own) from the `B` input in a manner that *can't* also depend on the `d` input.

LAW-B is is harder.  The most obvious way of formalizing this property would be the pseudolaw:

```
first f >>> arr snd = arr snd
```

which directly states that `first f` doesn't change the extracted (`arr snd`) second component.  However, Hughes points out that this is **too** restrictive, because it doesn't allow `first f` to have side effects (or at least any that can survive the pure action `arr snd`).  Instead, he provides the more complicated law:

```
first f >>> second (arr g)   =   second (arr g) >>> first f
```

The idea here is that, if `first f` ever modified the `d` value, then there would be *some* case where the following two actions would be different:

```
-- `first f` changes `inval` to something else
second (arr (const inval)) >>> first f
-- if we change it back, we change the action
second (arr (const inval)) >>> first f >>> second (arr (const inval))
```

But, because of LAW-B, we have:

```
second (arr (const inval)) >>> first f >>> second (arr (const inval))
-- associativity
= second (arr (const inval)) >>> (first f >>> second (arr (const inval)))
-- LAW-B
= second (arr (const inval)) >>> (second (arr (const inval)) >>> first f)
-- associativity
= (second (arr (const inval)) >>> (second (arr (const inval))) >>> first f
-- second and arr preserve composition
= second (arr (const inval >>> const inval)) >>> first f
-- properties of const function
= second (arr (const inval)) >>> first f
```

and so the actions are the same, contrary to our assumption.

HOWEVER, I conjecture that LAW-A and LAW-B are both redundant, because I believe (see my hesitation below) they follow from the other laws plus a "free theorem" for the signature:

```
first f :: forall d. Foo (B,d) (C,d)
```

Assuming `first` and `second` satisfy the no-side-effects laws:

```
first (arr f) = arr (first f)
second (arr f) = arr (second f)
```

then LAW-B can be rewritten as:

```
first f >>> second (arr g)              = second (arr g) >>> first f
-- no side effects for "second"
first f >>> arr (second g)              = arr (second g) >>> first f
-- definition of "second" for functions
= first f >>> arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y))  = arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y)) >>> first f
```

and this last statement is just the free theorem for `first f`.  (Intuitively, since `first f` is polymorphic in the type of `d`, any pure action on `d` is necessarily "invisible" to `first f`, so `first f` and any such action will commute.)  Similarly, there's a free theorem for:

```
first f >>> arr fst :: forall d. Foo (B,d) C
```

that captures the idea that, since this signature is polymorphic in `d`, no pure pre-action on `d` can affect the action:

```
arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y)) >>> (first f >>> arr fst) = first f >>> arr fst
```

But the left-hand side can be rewritten:

```
-- by associativity
(arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y)) >>> first f) >>> arr fst
-- by rewritten version of LAW-B
(first f >>> arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y))) >>> arr fst
-- by associativity
first f >>> (arr (\(x,y) -> (x, g y)) >>> arr fst)
-- `arr` preserves composition
first f >>> arr ((\(x,y) -> (x, g y)) >>> fst)
-- properties of fst
first f >>> arr fst
```

giving the right-hand side.

I only hesitate here because I'm not used to thinking about "free theorems" for possibly effectful arrows instead of functions, and so I'm not 100% sure that it goes through.

I'd be very interested to see if someone can come up with true counterexamples for these laws that violate LAW-A or LAW-B but satisfy the no-side-effects laws.  The reason your counterexamples violate LAW-A and LAW-B is that they violate the no-side-effects laws.  For your first example:

```
> runKMb (first (arr (2*))) (2,3)
Nothing
> runKMb (arr (first (2*))) (2,3)
Just (4,3)
```

and for your second:

```
> runKW (first (arr (2*))) (1,2)
("A",(2,2))
> runKW (arr (first (2*))) (1,2)
("",(2,2))
```