# How is `arr fst` a natural transformation?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, arrows

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62733726/11143763) a while ago. It was about the following arrow law:

```
arr fst . first f = f . arr fst -- (.) :: Category k => k b c -> k a b -> k a c
```

In the comments under the post [Asad Saeeduddin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad-saeeduddin) explained it in terms of **natural transformations**. I would like to check whether I got their explanation right and compare it a bit to [Bartosz Milewski's article on natural transformations](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations/).

So, the definition of **natural transformations** goes:

We have two categories `C` and `D` and functors `F, G : C ~> D`. A natural transformation `α` is a family of arrows in `D` such that:

1. These arrows go from the results of `F` to the results of `G`. That is, for every object `a` in `C` there exists an arrow (called the **component of `α` at `a`**) `α_a :: F a ~> G a`.
2. For every `f :: a ~> b`, `a` and `b` being objects in `C`, holds: `Gf . α_a = α_b . Ff`. That is the naturality.

Basically, we need to figure what four variables are in our case: `C`, `D`, `F` and `G`.

As far as I get it:

- `C` and `D` are the same category of arbitrary types, `k a b` being arrows in it, where `k` is the `Arrow` instance we are working with. Therefore, `F` and `G` are endofunctors.
- `F` is `(, c)` and `G` is `Identity`. In other words, if we no longer work with types, we map `F` with `first` and `G` with `id`. It would probably be easier **NOT** to think in terms of types as the `Category` and `Arrow` classes help us construct category's arrows, not objects

Is this right?

Moreover, [Bartosz Milewski wrote those ideas down](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations/) like that:

```
fmap f . alpha = alpha . fmap f
```

As far as I get it, we need a more general form for our purposes as here `alpha :: forall a. F a -> G a` deals with **Hask** only as the category it works with. Or am I wrong? Which place does `fmap` have in this picture?

Comment: I think you have G and F the wrong way around, but other than that you're right (including about the "more general form of `fmap`" stuff). `arr fst` has type `k (x, c) x`, and not `k x (x, c)`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin you are right - thank you. I edited the post.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I reread my post again, and I think I have spotted another inaccuracy. Shouldn't `C` be a category of arbitrary types, `k a b` being arrows in it? Because as of what is written down now, `arr fst` should have type `k ? ? -> k ? ?`, not `k ? ?`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I added some points about functor representation in types, which you mentioned under the post I linked. I would appreciate if you took a look at my attempt to be a bit more detailed about this. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It seems like what you have in the answer now is just a different way to say what you had before, so it still seems correct to me. When you specify a category, you usually characterize it by its morphisms, because typically the specification of morphisms ends up determining the objects. If we say that `C` is a "category of arrows" (as you did before), where a morphism from object `a` to `b` is a member of the arrow type `k a b`, we've implicitly ended up specifying that the objects are arbitrary types `a`, `b`, ...

Comment: A similar rule of thumb applies to functors: the morphism mapping of the functor ends up also specifying the object mapping, because you can't write the former without defining the latter. So other than for aesthetic reasons, there's no rule that we have to define our endofunctors on the arrow category in terms of their type constructor instead of their "fmap" operations (as you had before).

Comment: Adding an answer for the sake of completeness. even though between the comments and the edits I suspect you have mostly figured it out by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I get it:
>
> - `C` and `D` are the same category of arbitrary types, `k a b` being arrows in it, where `k` is the `Arrow` instance we are working with.
>   Therefore, `F` and `G` are endofunctors.
> - `F` is `(, c)` and `G` is `Identity`. In other words, if we no longer work with types, we map `F` with `first` and `G` with `id`.
>   [...]

Yup, that's it. Every choice of `k` and `c` in `arr fst :: k (b, c) b` gives us a natural transformation between the `(, c)` endofunctor and the identity functor in the `k`-category. Carrying out the specialisations gives us a signature that looks more obviously like that of a natural transformation:

```
arr @K (fst @_ @C) :: forall b. K (b, C) b
```

> Moreover, [Bartosz Milewski wrote those ideas
> down](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations)
> like that:
>
> ```
> fmap f . alpha = alpha . fmap f
> ```
>
> As far as I get it, we need a more general form for our purposes as
> here `alpha :: forall a. F a -> G a` deals with **Hask** only as the
> category it works with. Or am I wrong? Which place does `fmap` have in
> this picture?

Also correct. `fmap` would have to be replaced by whatever the appropriate morphism mappings are for the involved functors. In your example, these happen to be `first` and `id`, as you had noticed before, which brings us back to the arrow law we began with.

(As for replacing `fmap`, the method of `Functor` which abstracts from specific functor morphism mappings, by a more general analogue, that requires making the proper arrangements so that we can express functors involving non-**Hask** categories in Haskell code. You might want to have a look at how [*constrained-categories*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Functor-Constrained.html) and [*data-category*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category-0.10/docs/Data-Category-Functor.html) handle that.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is an `arr`-category(1<sup>st</sup> extract)? Do you mean `k`-category, where `k` is the `Arrow` instance at hand?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor Exactly. (I meant to write `k`-category; the `arr` there was a typo.)

Comment: also, are you sure about the type signature of `arr @K (fst @_ @C)`? Firstly, I can't see how `K` applied to one argument could appear in a type signature *on its own* (as `K a :: * -> *`). Moreover, GHCi tells us this: `arr @K (fst @_ @C) :: K (c, C) c`.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor That was another copyediting mistake. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: You mentioned *constrained-categories*. The author observed on [project's Git](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories) that it might get deprecated in favour of [*subhask*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/subhask), which you didn't mention. Why do you choose *constrained-categories* over *subhask*? Is the deprecation of the former a pending issue, or has it been waived?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor While I wasn't thinking of *subhask* while writing the answer, its category and functor classes are relevant examples as well. As for the deprecation, I'm pretty much sure it has been waived. *subhask* (whose scope, it's worth noting, is much wider than just introducing a more general category abstraction) hasn't had a new version since 2015, while *constrained-categories* is still actively maintained.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to worry about extra categories, because `arr fst` doesn't involve an arbitrary `Arrow`, just the `(,)` instance of it.

In Haskell, a function of type `f a -> g a` for some functors `f` and `c` is a natural transformation. In the case of `arr fst :: (b -> c) -> (b, c)`, let `f ~ (->) b` and `g ~ (,) b`.

Comment: What does it mean "`arr fst` doesn't involve an arbitrary `Arrow`, just the `(,)` instance of it"?

Comment: `arr` has a constrained type `Arrow a => a` in its signature, but the function returned by `arr fst` does not.

Comment: Truth be told, I highly doubt that. Moreover, here is what GHCi is telling me when I input `:t arr fst`: `arr fst :: Arrow a => a (c, b) c`.

Comment: By the way, I reckon `(b -> c) -> (b, c)` type to be uninhabited as `(B -> C) -> BC` is not a tautology (check `B = False` and `C = True`). Intuition may be that we are unable to apply the function-argument in general case.

Comment: But I might have just misunderstood your answer (that is probably the case). Can you add a bit more explanation, please?